# Selecting Cells with 2 Combo Boxes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a UserForm with three boxes. The first is Combobox1 of Students using a name range from Column A, next is Combobox2 of Standards referencing a line of code from Row 1, lastly is a frame with four Option buttons. What I would like to do is have the user select a student from that Combobox1 and then the Standard from Combobox2 and it will find the cell between these two and fill it in with the selected Option buttons value.

I have tried going on the internet to search for anything like this and I haven't been able to find anything. I am a little new to VBA so I am not how to use the entire code language yet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If ComboBox1.Value <> vbNullString And ComboBox2.Value <> vbNullString Then
        'write into cell
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select Student and Standard first"
    End If

    If Points.OptionButton1.Value = True Then
        ActiveCell.Value = OptionButton1.Caption
    ElseIf Points.OptionButton3.Value = True Then
        ActiveCell.Value = OptionButton3.Caption
    ElseIf Points.OptionButton4.Value = True Then
        ActiveCell.Value = OptionButton4.Caption
    ElseIf Points.OptionButton5.Value = True Then
        ActiveCell.Value = OptionButton5.Caption
    Else
        MsgBox "Please Select Point Value"
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub

    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Me.ComboBox2.List = Application.Transpose( _
        Worksheets("Anderson").Range("B1:K1").Value)

End Sub
```

I have figured out how to get it to do the last step (fill in the cell with a value), but I can't get the VBA to work when it comes to selecting the cell between the two values from Combobox1 (Students) and Combobox2 (Standards), when I click the Command button.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If Me.ComboBox1.Value <> "" And Me.ComboBox2.Value <> "" Then
    RowLookup = WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.ComboBox1.Value, Columns(1), 0)
    columnLookup = WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.ComboBox2.Value, Rows(1), 0)
    If Me.OptionButton1.Value = True Then
        Me.OptionButton1.Caption = Worksheets("Anderson").Cells(RowLookup, columnLookup).Value
        ActiveCell.Value = Me.OptionButton1.Caption
    ElseIf Me.OptionButton2.Value = True Then
         Me.OptionButton2.Caption = Worksheets("Anderson").Cells(RowLookup, columnLookup).Value
        ActiveCell.Value = Me.OptionButton2.Caption
    ElseIf Me.OptionButton3.Value = True Then
         Me.OptionButton3.Caption = Worksheets("Anderson").Cells(RowLookup, columnLookup).Value
        ActiveCell.Value = Me.OptionButton3.Caption
    ElseIf Me.OptionButton4.Value = True Then
         Me.OptionButton4.Caption = Worksheets("Anderson").Cells(RowLookup, columnLookup).Value
        ActiveCell.Value = Me.OptionButton4.Caption
    ElseIf Me.OptionButton5.Value = True Then
         Me.OptionButton5.Caption = Worksheets("Anderson").Cells(RowLookup, columnLookup).Value
        ActiveCell.Value = Me.OptionButton5.Caption
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select Point value"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "Please select student and standard first"
End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
For Each cell In Worksheets("Anderson").Range("A2:" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Address)
    If cell.Value = "" Then Exit For
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem cell.Value
Next

For Each cell In Worksheets("Anderson").Range("B1:" & Range("B1").End(xlToRight).Address)
    If cell.Value = "" Then Exit For
    Me.ComboBox2.AddItem cell.Value
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I see where I went wrong with my original code. However, I have tried running this code and it keeps giving me the error message "Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class" and highlights bot the  RowLookup = WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.ComboBox1.Value, Columns(1), 0)
    columnLookup = WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.ComboBox2.Value, Rows(1), 0) every time I click the command button.

Comment: Can you show your coding? Because i not facing any error when click the command button.

Comment: I used the code that you wrote, and tried it in the original document and then tried rebuilding the document and it keeps coming up with the same error. "Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class" and then it highlights "RowLookup = WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.ComboBox1.Value, Columns(1), 0) columnLookup = WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.ComboBox2.Value, Rows(1), 0) when I ask for the Debug.

Comment: I need to see your document and code just can detect the error.

Comment: How can I send you my document?